# Vertical RelativeLayout: how to achieve fixed header and footer and scrollable main area?

Tags: android

This is a layout I'm having problems with (this is for ListActivity):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/path" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negative_button"
        style="@style/Button"
        android_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What happens right now is the list is below header `TextView` ("path") as it should be, the button is at the bottom also as it should be, but the `ListView` is not aligned between the header (textview) and footer (button). Instead, the button is simply slapped on top of listview. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what it looks like now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the footer and header before the list, try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- to see the button, you must to declare its width/height here
         and not (as I think you did) in the style.xml -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negative_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <!-- also layout_weight doesnot change anything in RelativeLayout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/path"
        android:layout_above="@id/negative_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to set an orientation in RelativeLayout, no? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example

Comment: Yes exactly, I just copy pasted his code but the orientation isn't needed, I'll delete it.
Thanks :)

Comment: That didn't help. ListView still spans down to the bottom of the screen, and button is just floating over. Also, it says "circular dependence cannot exist in RelativeLayout", but builds .apk regardless.

Comment: Edited my answer, please give it an another try ;)

Comment: I have honestly tried setting button width and height as you've said, but it of course did not work. There's no problem with button size. There's only a problem with relative placement of a button and `ListView`. Also note that this is not just any activity, it's a ListActivity, so the list is kind of built-in. Is that relevant?

Comment: Normally it's no relevant: `"ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list""`

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` "empty" should not be below the `TextView` "empty".
If the `Button` must be at the bottom of the screen you can use

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

For the `Button`

Otherwise you can use this layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/path">

        <ListView
           android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@android:id/empty"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@android:id/list" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/negative_button"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or ever add the `Button` as a footer of you `Listview` :

```
mListView.addFooterView(mButton);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

Comment: I am using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, accidentally edited it out of my question. Fixed.

Comment: `addFooterView` also doesn't help (or maybe I'm just not supposed to take a button inflated from layout and it it to layout again with `addFooterView`).

Answer (score 0):

The only things that you used are the `ListView`, the first `TextView` as a "top bar" and the `Button` as a "bottom bar", right? If it is the case, why did you keep the empty `TextView`?
Try to remove it and try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
    <!-- work also with android:layout_height="0dip" -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negative_button"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Saw on these questions, it might be help you:
1. [Layout for ListView at top and Buttons in Bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403212/layout-for-listview-at-top-and-buttons-in-bottom)
2. [Android Layout with ListView between a "top bar" and "bottom bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989883/android-layout-with-listview-between-a-top-bar-and-bottom-bar)
3. [Add a button in bottom of listview when the listview is empty (using ListActivity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687171/add-a-button-in-bottom-of-listview-when-the-listview-is-empty-using-listactivit)

Hope this will be helpful and you'll have the expected result.

Comment: I believe the view was in the tutorial I used to master ListActivity, I have no idea what it's for and didn't bother to check. I don't believe `LinearLayout` will work, I've had similar problems before and I was never able to get header and footer fixed top and bottom and the scrollview filling whatever space is left in between. But I will try again!

Comment: On virtual layout (Graphic Layout in Eclipse), this layout above works pretty well. Let us know if you find the answer.